# Jasmine Angular component is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

*I am a bit new to Angular 7 and totally new to it's unit testing framework Jasmine*

So i have been following the docs of Jasmine and also some tutorials. I have component called `TestTableComponent`. Now the component is a bit hard-coded. Anyways, i think the issue i'm facing hardly has anything to do with the component itself, so i am not including the component's code here.

I created a testing class, inside `test-table.component.spec.ts`. The code is as follows :

```
// Required Imports have been made. Not including as unnecessary.

describe('TestTableComponent',  async() => 
{
let component: TestTableComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestTableComponent>;
let de: DebugElement;


beforeEach(async(() => 
{
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations:[TestTableComponent],
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]}).compileComponents();
}));
beforeEach(() =>
{
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    de = fixture.debugElement;
})


it('should check if data is returned by the API')
{

    const result = await component.GetEmployees;
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
}
});
```

The issue here is that, when i execute `ng test`, it seems to run the test based on this class. In the console of the browser, i get one error(for which, `Jasmine` says `1 component is pending`) as follows :

> Cannot read property `GetEmployees` of undefined.

Now, this clearly means that `TestTableComponent` is never initialized. I am just wondering why? Is `beforeEach` not being executed? If it is, then why is `component` undefined ?

**UPDATE : Including the component's code**

**Test-table.component.ts**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTable, MatTableDataSource, MatDialogRef, Sort, ShowOnDirtyErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { TestTableItem } from './test-table-datasource';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UpdateModalDialogComponent } from '../update-modal-dialog/update-modal-dialog.component';
import { MessagePopUpComponent } from '../message-pop-up/message-pop-up.component';
@Component({
selector: 'app-test-table',
templateUrl: './test-table.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./test-table.component.css']
})
export class TestTableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatTable, { static: false }) table: MatTable<TestTableItem>;
private myCollection: TestTableItem[] = [];

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.myCollection);// Observable<TestTableItem>;
/** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
displayedColumns = ['id', 'fname', 'salary', 'age', 'image', 'actions'];
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dialog:MatDialog) { }


ngOnInit() {

   this.GetAllEmployees();
 }

async GetAllEmployees()
{
 this.dataSource = await this.GetEmployees();
}
public async GetEmployees()
{
 this.myCollection = await this.http.get<TestTableItem[]>('http://localhost:22371/api/employee/GetEmployees/').toPromise();
return new MatTableDataSource(this.myCollection);

}
```

***Please note that i am not including all the functions inside the class, as that would make this post unnecessarily big!***

Comment: You should have a ```fixture.detectChanges()``` at the beginning of the test. The first ```fixture.detectChanges()``` calls the onInit inside the component. This will probably not exactly fix your problem though. Could you please share the component definition as well. Are there any dependencies inside your component?

Comment: Move the setup for asynchronous tests into the `async` beforeEach. Your function is racing the setups in a separate thread. Asynchronous calls happen on another thread, so if the `beforeEach` starts and the test starts immediately after. The test is hitting the await before the `beforeEach` has initialized it

Comment: Your mistake is this line: `const result = await component.GetEmployees;`. You did not include round brackets (). That's why the compiler is complaining a "property is undefined" even though it's a method.

Comment: @Riv, can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig, yes, my component has dependencies. I would share the code too, however, where do i call `fixture.detectChanges()` ? In the `beforeEach(async()` or the regular `beforeEach` ?

Comment: @Riv, i put braces, however, the same issue persists. And the compiler never complains about the method directly, rather it says that the `component`, itself, is undefined

Comment: it depends. If you are using ```ChangeDetection.OnPush``` you would call that inside the ```it``` after you made up the setup for a test case (like setting an input property). If you are using ```ChangeDetection.Default``` you could just add that after ```component = fixture.componentInstance;```

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig, where is `ChangeDetection` being set.. ? I don't see it in my code ...

Comment: Please share your component code. I would assume that the component cannot be initialized because there are missing dependencies.

Comment: If you haven't set that, then you are using ```ChangeDetection.Default```. So you could add the ```fixture.detectChanges``` safely into the before each setup.

Comment: Recheck my updated post

Answer (score 1):

You writing the wrong `it()` function syntax, it should take first parameter is the string description and second parameter is the callback that implement your test:

```
it('should check if data is returned by the API', async(() =>{
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const result = component.GetEmployees();
    fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{
      expect(result).toBeDefined();
    })
}))
```

Comment: Now it throws the following error : `Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("Size.px]=14 style="width:70px; margin:0px 30px 5px 50px;">
        <input matInput placeholder="ID" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="searchId" name="searchId" value="">
      </mat-form-field>`. Now `mat-field-form` is a part of the template. So.. what does this mean actually ?

Comment: It mean you need also need to provide its dependecies to the TestBed which is `FormsModule ` in this case, also im not seeing GetEmployees defined within the table component

Comment: and it yelling error, which mean now `it()` function is working

Comment: Yep, also you need to provide Material's module that your component used, the TestBed is like a NgModule for testing, all dependicies in generals needed to imports

Comment: I included it now, kindly recheck

Comment: You should call the function  `GetEmployees` : component.GetEmployees() so it can return value, updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Besides the wrong `it()` syntax @Ethan mentioned. You need to set either `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` to your TestBed or you need to include missing dependencies into your TestBed.

I personally prefer the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` approach since imho a unit test does not need to test whether some third party library works right, but that is up to you. This approach is usually referred to as *shallow testing a component*

The schema is set like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations:[TestTableComponent],
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]

}).compileComponents();
```

Please have a look at the official documentation on [nested component tests](https://angular.io/guide/testing#nested-component-tests)